# Proof that every arithmetic progression which might contain a prime does so.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

It's been bugging me all afternoon - is there an easy proof that if $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ there is a prime number $p$ of the form $p = an+b$?
I'm aware of Dirichlet's theorem that there are in fact infinitely many primes of this form but am hoping there is an elementary proof of this weaker form.

The fact that I have been unable to find any proof of this online suggests to me that it's in fact very easy and I am simply missing something obvious.

Comment: It's not hard to deduce the full form of Dirichlet from this special case.

Comment: For any $k$ there is a prime of the form $a^kn+b$.

Comment: @Wojowu ... and it is trivial anyway if $a=1$

Comment: So is it the case that the reason I don't find any proofs online that in fact it is hard, and almost immediately implies the full Dirichlet's theorem?

Comment: Correct. ${}{}$

Comment: Thank you  you've dissolved my problem

Comment: @Wojowu Is there a reference for this generalization ?

Comment: @Peter You apply Dirichlet to $a^k$ and $b$

Comment: @Wojowu Oh my dear, how could I miss that ? Maybe it is the heat we have in Frankenthal :)

Comment: Yes, it's hard to prove, @AndrewSlattery. Whether it implies the full Dirichlet theorem depends on what precisely one considers the full theorem. What Dirichlet proved was more than just that there are infinitely many primes in every arithmetic progression $an + b$ with $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, he proved that the sum of the reciprocals of the primes in such a progression diverges (and even some more). That "each such progression contains at least one prime" implies "each such progression contains infinitely many primes" is easy, but getting to "the sum of the reciprocals diverges" isn't.